# Weird result in probability

Tags: probability

Consider the following gambling game:

- Toss a coin that has probability 3/4 of landing on heads. For every round that it doesn't land on heads, add $2^{i-1}$ to your score, where $i$ is the round number. The game stops on the first "heads".

I want to calculate the expected score, $X$. I can do this in two ways:

1. The probability of getting a score of $2^n - 1$ is the probability of "winning" $n$ rounds, so $E[X] = (\frac{1}{4})^1 1 + (\frac{1}{4})^2 3 + (\frac{1}{4})^3 7 + ... = \frac{2}{3}$.
2. Let $X_i$ mark the probability that the ith bit in the binary representation of $X$ is non-zero. This probability is $(1/4)^i$. So by linearity of expectancy we have $E[X]=E[X_1]+2^1  E[X_2]+...+2^n E[X_n]+...=(\frac{1}{4})+2(\frac{1}{4})^2+4(\frac{1}{4})^3+...=\frac{1}{2}$.

Which is correct?

Comment: For the second approach, don't you also need that all the previous bits are zero?

Comment: Does the game stop as soon as the first head is tossed?

Comment: @paw88789 Yes, I'll add this clarification

Comment: You say: " for every round add $2^i-1$ to your score...". So if you win $n$ rounds $2^n-1$ is not your score. It is just the last increment of your score. So approach 1 is not correct. Am I wrong?

Comment: The probability of getting a score of $2^n-1$ is the probability to get $n-1$ times heads then tails, which happens with probability $3/4^n$, not $1/4^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miscalculated: the first should be
$$
E[X] = (3/4)(1/4)^1 1 + (3/4)(1/4)^2 3 + (3/4)(1/4)^3 7 + \cdots = \frac{1}{2}
$$
Note that, for example, the probability of getting heads on the second try is $(1/4)$ (the probability of missing the first throw) multiplied by $(3/4)$ (the probability of getting the second throw).

Comment: Oh, I guess it's sillier than I thought. Thanks :-)